# COUNT(), ORDER BY(), WHILE{}

Tags: mysql, select, pdo, count, sql-order-by

PDO + mySQL: This does not output a random row:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows, somefield, otherfield ORDER BY RAND()"
```

And if I use `"SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows, somefield, otherfield"`, I can't also use a while loop (it stops at one row)

Any idea why? I can't use COUNT() and also have criterias or loops?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it boils down to: I'm just searching for a proper direct way to count the result of WHATEVER I put in a query (so I can skip the COUNT(*) thing).. Where is mysql_num_rows for PDO?

Comment: I'm skipping COUNT(*) now and instead use if ($row = $STH->fetch()) {} for basic check. Or count($STH->fetchAll()) for exact number of rows

Comment: Do you just want `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?

Comment: Maybe. Will look into it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `count()` is an aggregate function and returns only a single record - in your case the numbe of records in your table.

In MySQL you can mix this with normal fields which results in this weird behaviour. In other DB engines this query would throw an error.

If you really need a random row **and** the table row count in a single query you can do

```
SELECT somefield, 
       otherfield,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) from your_table) as numrows
from your_table
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Damn.. I'm trying so hard to find an easy quick solid way to just COUNT the number of returned rows, while still be able to sort and use them. Without extra queries. This was so easy and direct with mysql: mysq_num_rows

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to group data?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numrows, somefield, otherfield
FROM table t
GROUP BY somefield, otherfield
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Your original query is not allowed in most databases and is inconsistent with the SQL standard.  MySQL happens to support this syntax through an extension.  The `count(*)` says the query is an aggregation.  Without a `group by`, only one row is returned -- the entire data set is treated as a single group.